# Count each item in Column A if Corresponding month is THIS month

Tags: excel, google-sheets

```
CD         12/1/2014    CD        =countif($A:$A, C2)
Car        12/5/2014    Car       =countif($A:$A, C3) 
CD         12/7/2014    Computer  =countif($A:$A, C4)
Computer   12/20/2014
CD         12/31/2014
CD         1/1/2015
```

I want to count how many CD's were sold in December 2014. To be displayed in another cell
I can count the amount of times CD occurs but I just can't figure out how to count CD based on the associated date.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of date(month). I feel like this is a very easy problem to solve and its driving me crazy!

No pivot tables please.

Comment: In Excel (have no clue about Google Spreadsheet) try `Countifs()` - It allows for multiple criteria

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for without the need for hidden helper columns.

```
=countifs(A:A,C2,B:B,">="&date(year(today()),Month(today()),1),B:B,"<="&date(year(today()),month(today())+1,1)-1)
```

Countifs allows counting based on multiple criteria. Broken down:

`A:A,C2`: Searching for CD in Column A

`B:B,">="&date(year(today()),Month(today()),1)`: Look for dates that are greater than or equal to the first day of the current month.

`B:B,"<="&date(year(today()),month(today())+1,1)-1`: Look for dates that are less than or equal to the last day of the current month.

Comment: oh! I get it. I was trying to throw in multiple nested IFs and it was just becoming to sloppy. Works like a charm btw, thank you for the info on the countif and method for pulling current month!

Answer (score 0):

I would create some hidden helper columns with month and year.
This might not be exactly what you are looking for in terms of layout, but it does what you want.  I'm sure you can apply these ideas to your specific needs.  Or comment and I can update the answer.

[image: Setup]

Then use the following formulas:

```
C2: =IF(B2="","",TEXT($B2,"m"))
D2: =IF(B2="","",TEXT($B2,"yyyy"))

G2: =COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,C:C,$J$2,D:D,$J$3)
```

Then you set Column F to contain the items you are counting.

use columns I & J as shown for the search parameters, of month and year.

edit: added more commnents

Answer (score 0):

In case you want an overview per month of the number of articles sold (using google spreadsheets) you could try:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:B10,row(B2:B10)}, "select Col1, count(Col3) group By Col1 pivot Month(Col2)+1 label Col1 'sales per month'"))
```

(assuming articles are in Col A and dates in Col B).

For just this month:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:B10,row(B2:B10)}, "select Col1, count(Col3) where month(Col2)+1=12 group By Col1 "))
```

Answer (score 0):

For those with a real problem of this kind (not just homework?) and no aversion to pivot tables it is a pivot table that is exactly the right tool for this job. A PivotTable in particular for its facility to group by month.

Comment: Real world problem with some work of mine. Problem was simplified and isolated to be easily tackled. Primary reason I strayed away from pivot tables is the need for 50+ people to be within the workbook at any given time. No time/man power to test if changing views/pivot tables would alter someone else's view. At a loss how to word that search in google, so here I am!